# GFCI on an induction range?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, gfci, range

Based on my reading, NEC2023 says that if a stove is within 6 feet of the edge of a kitchen sink then the stove needs to be GFCI protected.

Modern induction ranges pull 50 amps and (usually) need their own, dedicated, circuit out of the electric panel in the house. This dedicated circuit comes with a dedicated outlet and dedicated power wire.

My kitchen isn't big enough to move a freestanding range more than 6 feet away from the edge of the sink. Is it accurate, then, that that the only proper way to install the wiring to power an induction range would be to use a GFCI breaker in the panel?

Comment: What state are you in? Have they fully adopted nec 2023?

Comment: New York. I don't know whether NEC2023 is fully adopted. Regardless of whether my area is using a slightly older version of the code or not, I'm trying to be looking forward on the wiring job rather than seeing what I can get away with.

Comment: If you're on 2020 there's very little advantage to putting in the GFCI. There is a safety improvement but it's tiny in practical application, due to induction not having exposed electric elements.

Comment: @KMJ Your comment here seems to contradict your posted answer.  The advantage is being compliant with electrical code.

Comment: Does the 6 ft mean sideways along a counter?  Or would a sink along the wall, opposite an island with a cooktop (or vice versa) qualify as "within 6 ft?"

Comment: My understanding is that a rough paraphrase of the guideline is "the most reasonable cord path must never be within 6 feet of the edge of the sink". Is that how everyone else reads it?

Comment: @maple_shaft I'm saying if you are on 2020 rather than 2023 and not within six feet of a sink, it's not 'getting away with' anything to leave out the GFCI, and the benefit to putting one in anyway is quite small.

Comment: @THill3 it's six feet from the outlet to the edge of the sink. If you can't reach between the two locations with six feet of string, you don't need a GFCI in 2020.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're on NEC2020 or up, yes, a GFCI is now required in a kitchen on a 250V circuit in many or all circumstances. Here's my favorite Eaton chart on the matter.

[image: Eaton GFCI/AFCI chart]

For NEC 2020, the triggering requirement is the outlet being within six feet of the edge of a sink. Do note the code says in 210.8:

> 'For the purposes of this section, the distance from receptacles shall
> be measured as the shortest path the power supply cord connected to
> the receptacle would follow without piercing a floor, wall, ceiling,
> or fixed barrier.'

So you don't have to beeline the six feet. A freestanding range can be closer than 6 feet to the sink so long as the receptacle itself is further away than that. Heck, if it's close to working, you could add a splash barrier between the range and the sink to buy yourself more distance.

This might mean purchase of an expensive 50A GFCI breaker. Or if you're running a new circuit, it might mean making sure that the receptacle is six feet away from the edge of the sink.

Once you're on NEC 2023, you need the GFCI no matter what. 210.8 now says

> GFCI protection shall be provided for the branch circuit or outlet
> supplying the following appliances rated 150 volts or less to ground
> and 60 amperes or less, single- or 3-phase:
>
> Electric ranges

Comment: Does anything change if the range is hardwired instead of being plugged into a receptacle?

Comment: No. The code language doesn't refer to receptacles, it refers to outlets. An outlet can be a junction box transition to a piece of flexible conduit. It's kind of weird language.